# Reading an Outlook 2016 email with Lotuscript

Tags: outlook, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a Notes application that reads an opened Outlook mailbox and creates a document for each email. This worked fine for Outlook 2013, but we recently upgraded to Outlook 2016. When we tried to run the program we started getting "Automation object" errors when trying to access parts of the MailItem through OLE. It isn't everything as subject works fine, but SenderEmailAddress does not.

```
Dim docMemo as NotesDocument
Const olFInbox = 6

Set olapp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set ns = olapp.getnamespace("mapi")
Set inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFInbox)
Set col = inbox.items

ForAll msg In col
    Set docMemo = New NotesDocument(db)
    If UCase(msg.SenderEmailType) = "EX" Then
        email = msg.Sender.getExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
    Else
        email = msg.SenderEmailAddress
    End If

    Call docMemo.Replaceitemvalue("Form", "Memo")
    Call docMemo.Replaceitemvalue("Subject", msg.subject)
    Call docMemo.Replaceitemvalue("Body", msg.HTMLBody)
    Call docMemo.Replaceitemvalue("From", msg.SenderName)
    Call docMemo.Replaceitemvalue("SMTPOriginator", email)
    Call docMemo.Replaceitemvalue("PostedD", msg.SentOn)
    Call docMemo.Replaceitemvalue("CBy", currentUser)

    Call docMemo.Save(true, false)

End ForAll
```

Is there a option or parameter that could be set that's blocking LotusScript from being able to read all properties of the MailItem?

Comment: Are you still on Outlook **32bit** version? Notes can deal with 32bit only...

Comment: Yes, we are still using 32bit.

Comment: Are you sure that this item / field really exists in every outlook message? It's been a long while that I did something like that but I remember I started with creating a VBA macro inside the Outlook client doing more or less what I wanted my LotusScript to do, then let it run in Debug mode. Have a look at the various fields and their data types

Comment: I'm not sure if it was this tool or another one that I used, but when I ran into cases like this I always found it useful to look at the raw MAPI data. Much like Notes itself, MAPI is quite upredictable about what items exist (properties, actually, in MAPI lingo IIRC).  https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mfcmapi

Comment: @LotharMueller I wrote a test script that looped through and printed the names of all the properties in the mailitem object, and the ones I couldn't access did appear in that list.

Comment: We ended up ditching this code and fixing another issue that was just stopping us from using an outlook mail rule to redirect the emails to a mail-in database. Thanks for all the assistance anyway. @RichardSchwartz I'll take a look at this tool just in case this happens to come up again.